# Update data in multiple table from import

Tags: mysql

I've base main table: **`products`**

- This table contains: **`ID`** and **`SKU`**

I've second table: **`product_details`**

- This table contains: `product_id` `title` `description`

column `id` from first table = `product_id` from second table

and now,

How to update `title` and `description` in table `product_details` from import csv, when in csv file I've only SKU ?

Of course, I just want to know if it's possible at all and is it logical.

eg is there any sql query that when i send a SKU then it first checks the product id that corresponds to the sent SKU in table products and then for that product_id it updates the data in the table product_details?

Comment: To answer your question if it's possible, Yes.

Comment: Trigger (before insert) seems to be an option for this task! https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html